# How to create equal column width in this table?

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm making a table for my regression outputs in latex. However, due to the significance subscript using `\multicolumn` latex puts all the extra width into the last column. I want the columns to be equally wide, how do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{AEX, daily, from 01-01-2020}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash} c c c c}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\midrule 
$b_1$         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
$b_2$    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
$\beta$     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
$\omega$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
$\delta$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\ 
\midrule
 AIC           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
 BIC           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\addlinespace[1ex]
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\textsuperscript{***}, 
  \textsuperscript{**}, 
  \textsuperscript{*} denote significance at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level, respectively. Standard errors are denoted in brackets.} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` does nothing in a c column, that is specifying how to do line breaking but `c` columns are always one-line

Comment: Do you want to equally distribute the extra width to all columns or do you want to keep the table as wide as it would naturally be while making the text below it narrower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % for second example

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{AEX, daily, from 01-01-2020}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c c}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\midrule 
$b_1$         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
$b_2$    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
$\beta$     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
$\omega$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
$\delta$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\ 
\midrule
 AIC           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
 BIC           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\textsuperscript{***}, 
  \textsuperscript{**}, 
  \textsuperscript{*} denote significance at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level, respectively. Standard errors are denoted in brackets. 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{AEX, daily, from 01-01-2020}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\ 
\midrule 
$b_1$         &      -0.012   &      -0.052   &      -0.156** \\
            &      (0.04)   &      (0.06)   &      (0.06)   \\
$b_2$    &               &       0.034   &       0.097*  \\
            &               &      (0.05)   &      (0.04)   \\
$\beta$     &               &               &       0.439***\\
            &               &               &      (0.06)   \\
$\omega$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\
$\delta$       &       0.529***&       0.530***&       0.518***\\
            &      (0.03)   &      (0.03)   &      (0.02)   \\ 
\midrule
 AIC           &     196   &     196   &     196   \\          
 BIC           &       0.001   &       0.003   &       0.235   \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[] \textsuperscript{***},  \textsuperscript{**}, \textsuperscript{*} denote significance at the 1\%, 5\% and 10\% level, respectively. Standard errors are denoted in brackets.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a hero! I want to use the first wider output.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to fixing the width of the table's footnote material to that of the `tabular` environment -- an objective that may be achieved easily by employing the machinery of the `threeparttable` package -- you should also aim to align the numbers in the three data columns on their respective decimal markers. I suggest you employ the `dcolumn` package's machinery in order to achieve your second objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\sym[1]{^{#1}}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{AEX, daily, from 01-01-2020}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\toprule
Variable & 
\mc{Model 1} & 
\mc{Model 2} & 
\mc{Model 3} \\ 
\midrule 
$b_1$   &-0.012         & -0.052        &-0.156\sym{**} \\
        &(0.04)         & (0.06)        &(0.06)         \\
$b_2$   &               &  0.034        & 0.097\sym{*}  \\
        &               & (0.05)        &(0.04)         \\
$\beta$ &               &               & 0.439\sym{***}\\
        &               &               &(0.06)         \\
$\omega$& 0.529\sym{***}& 0.530\sym{***}& 0.518\sym{***}\\
        &(0.03)         &(0.03)         &(0.02)         \\
$\delta$& 0.529\sym{***}& 0.530\sym{***}& 0.518\sym{***}\\
        &(0.03)         &(0.03)         &(0.02)         \\ 
\midrule
 AIC    &     \mc{196}  &    \mc{196}   &   \mc{196}    \\          
 BIC    &       0.001   &      0.003    &     0.235     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\footnotesize\raggedright
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]Standard errors are shown in parentheses. $\sym{***}$, $\sym{**}$, and $\sym{*}$ denote significance at the 1\%, 5\%, and 10\% levels, respectively. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `threeparttable` and `siunitx` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sisetup{table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-format=-1.3
         }
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{AEX, daily, from 01-01-2020}
\label{tab:3parttable}  
\begin{tabular}{ >{$}c<{$} SSS}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3}\\
\midrule
b_1     & -0.012            & -0.052            & -0.156\tnote{**}      \\
        & (0.04)            & (0.06)            & (0.06)                \\
b_2     &                   & 0.034             & 0.097\tnote{*}        \\
        &                   & (0.05)            & (0.04)                \\
\beta   &                   &                   & 0.439\tnote{***}      \\
        &                   &                   & (0.06)                \\
\omega  & 0.529\tnote{***}  & 0.530\tnote{***}  & 0.518\tnote{***}      \\
        & (0.03)            & (0.03)            & (0.02)                \\
\delta  & 0.529\tnote{***}  & 0.530\tnote{***}  & 0.518\tnote{***}      \\
        & (0.03)            & (0.03)            & (0.02)                \\
\midrule
 AIC    & {196}             & {196}             & {196}                 \\
 BIC    & 0.001             & 0.003             & 0.235                 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize
\item[*], \item[**]\ and \item[***]\ denote significance at the \SI{1}{\%}, \SI{5}{\%} and \SI{10}{\%}, respectively. Standard errors are denoted in brackets.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. What's with `\tnote{***}***`, though?

Comment: @Mico, huh, what a typing errors. I will correct (erase superfluous ****) asap.